# How to use ngx_bootstrap datepicker with french version

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap datepicker in my angular project. I want to use the French version of datepicker, but it always gives me the English version. Here's my code :

html :

```
 <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Date de l'aller :" bsDatepicker formControlName="dateDepart" />
```

component.ts:

```
import { defineLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
import { fr } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
defineLocale('fr', fr);
```

Any help, please, on how to use the French ngx-boostrap datepicker version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you defined locale but haven't actually set it. Inject `BsLocaleService` from `ngx-bootstrap/datepicker`  in your component and call its `use('fr')` method. Check the example here - https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#locales (go to `component` tab and take a look at the code)

Comment: it gives me this error  when i click the date input :TypeError: Object(...)(...) is null
Stack trace:
calculateReducer@webpack-internal:///../../../../ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/reducer/bs-datepicker.reducer.js:146:49
bsDatepickerReducer@webpack-internal:///../../../../ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/reducer/bs-datepicker.reducer.js:37:20

Comment: Ok, I made a small example for you. Check `main.ts` and `change-locale.ts` http://plnkr.co/edit/MIch2j58Ro5btsQcvDAw?p=preview

Comment: Documentation link : https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/datepicker?tab=overview

Answer (score 8):

For Spanish (Datepicker), add this code to app.module :

```
import { BsDatepickerModule, BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { defineLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
import { esLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/locale';
defineLocale('es', esLocale);

export class AppModule { 
  constructor( private bsLocaleService: BsLocaleService){
    this.bsLocaleService.use('es');//fecha en español, datepicker
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to set up locales for ngx-bootstrap datepicker in modules of Angular.

First we import our locale(s) in app.module.ts :

```
import { defineLocale } from "ngx-bootstrap/chronos";
import { nbLocale } from "ngx-bootstrap/locale";
defineLocale("nb", nbLocale); //only setting up Norwegian bokmaal (nb) in this sample
export class AppModule {
 constructor(private bsLocaleService: BsLocaleService) {
    this.bsLocaleService.use('nb');
    }
}
```

Now all our ngx-bootstrap datepickers will have the specified locale Norwegian. You can of course switch to other locales, remember to type in the string literals for the locals as lowercase.